# Sum Up individual DB sizes to a total number

Tags: sql

Created the query following to tally all DB space used by all our production instances. The query works great and produces results for "DB size" along with columns to show the related server and customer.

What I have been unable to do is programmatically have the query output the sum of all DB sizes at the end of the query run. Tried to create a scalar variable set to "0" and then add each Db size returned by the SELECT statement, but could not accomplish that.

My next goal is to learn how to directly write the query results to a CSV file.

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(database_id),
[Size in MB] = CAST(((SUM(Size)* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)),   -- DB size in MB

--  Add a column with who the customer
CASE 
        WHEN DB_NAME(database_id) = 'xxxx'  THEN  ' xxxx'
        WHEN (DB_NAME(database_id) IN ('ARSystem' , 'xxxx' , 'SmartReporting'))  THEN  ' xxxx'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
END  as Customer,
-- Get the server Name so we can assiciate to which xxxx, xxxxod or xxxx the instance is in
CASE
        WHEN  SUBSTRING(@@SERVERNAME,3,3) = 'uxx'  THEN ' xxxx'
        ELSE '????'
END   as    '  Area'
FROM   sys.master_files
WHERE  DB_NAME(database_id) NOT IN ('master', 'tempdev','tempdb')
GROUP BY      GROUPING SETS
          (
            (DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc),
            (DB_NAME(database_id))
          )
ORDER BY      DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc DESC
```

Sample of output resuls copied to excel
Server Name Database Name Size in MB Customer Area xxxxxx001 XXXXXXXXX 1001.88 Big_Customer Production xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx TOTAL MB Disk space used is: 29,443,247.13 TOTAL GB Disk space used is: 29,443.25 TOTAL TB Disk space used is: 29.44

Comment: You need to tag with database platform, and post a [mcve] including the sql.

Comment: Hello all, again.  haven't figured out how to add my code and results to the question asked earlier about summing DB size for overall disk space occupied.  The add comments only allows a small piece of code to be added.....

Comment: Sample of output resuls copied to excel 

Server Name Database Name   Size in MB Customer   Area
xxxxxx001 XXXXXXXXX   1001.88  Big_Customer   Production
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  TOTAL MB Disk space used is:     29,443,247.13  
  TOTAL GB Disk space used is:     29,443.25  
  TOTAL TB Disk space used is:     29.44

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I think you can edit your question and add as much additional information as your question needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION` your query with

```
SELECT [Database Name] = 'SUM', [Size in MB] = SUM(CAST(((SUM(Size)* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)))
...
```

where the ... represents the other parts of this query. Then, you will need to remove your initial `ORDER BY` and implement a new `ORDER BY` clause that would take into account both the normal records and the unioned aggregate, like

```
ORDER BY [Database Name] = 'SUM', DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc DESC
```